# How to Find Out if a "Google Error" has been Made?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

From time to time, someone searches on Google and comes up with a misleading result. For instance, searching for ["Web Service Security"](https://www.google.com/search?q=web%20service%20security) will find the both the recent ["Security Fundamentals for Web Services"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648318.aspx), and the ancient ["Building Secure Web Services"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648643.aspx).

Recently, I've noticed many people using the term "ASP" to refer to ASP.NET. One problem with that is that searching on ["ASP"](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp) will not only find ASP.NET, it will also find ["Active Server Pages"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286483.aspx) and ["ASP Tutorial"](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/).

Yesterday, in the question ["Writing to a text file using ASP"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484319/writing-to-a-text-file-using-asp), the OP stated that he was "totally new to ASP". In a comment, I asked if there was a reason he was using the obsolete "Classic ASP" instead of ASP.NET. This led to a number of comments accusing me of "spamming" the [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) tag, and also led to the deletion of my comment.

What is a proper way to find out whether someone is deliberately using an outdated technology without being accused of "spamming"?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused ... not sure what you're getting at. I think, you may just need to do what you did - comment and clarify what they mean.  I think, editing it with what you believe is correct intention

Comment: Without knowing text exact text of your comment, it impossible to say why they took so much offense to it, but it sounds like the [tag:asp-classic] community needs to relax.  "Why are you using an obsolete technology" to a brand new user seems like a valid question to me.  And given the question originally had the [tag:asp-net] tag, it seems the user really has no clue what they are using.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Hey, it's only obsolete if it doesn't do the *job I need done*  :P

Comment: @Coffee very true, but a brand new user usually wouldn't be supporting a legacy system.  Sounds more like they didn't know any better.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - hmm..  - touche , gotcha !

Comment: So, the fight is now not only between Microsoft technology on one side and the rest of the world on the other, we now have a fight between old and older MS stacks... interesting...

Comment: @rene: it's not an "older" stack - it's truly been replaced (13 years ago), and is no longer supported. If a new user needs to work on Classic ASP as part of his job, fine. But this user sounded like he didn't know the difference - in which case, he should not be starting off by learning "Classic ASP".

Comment: @psubsee2003: the comment was deleted, but not by me

Comment: The question's headline and what you're asking do not amount to the same thing. Now that's Meta.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I think the end result - OP switching and thanking you speaks for itself.

Comment: Obsolete and unsupported, but a depressing number of complex legacy systems used it, and for some of them the developers probably couldn't get support for a rewrite ("It works, it's in production, why touch it?"), so they hang around until they become the next developer's problem...it's been a while since I've seen one, but I know they're still out there.

Answer (score 39):

I think you did try the right thing.

If an OP claims to be new in a technology today and followers of the tag have knowledge of a more recent, newer, replaced, superseded technology it is fair to ask the OP if that newer technology might have been overlooked.

It is obvious that suggesting to use [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) instead of [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) is beyond limits, but the confusion about ASP and ASP.NET is not unthinkable for new users in the Microsoft Web stack.

Steps to find out if outdated technology is used on purpose:

1. Do the tags match the used technology (in this case the ASP.NET tag was wrong)? If not: retag
2. Leave a comment for the OP: 
   *The tags and your question indicate you're using technology that is advised not to be used for new development/projects. Are you constrained by external factors to this setup?*
3. Based on the feedback of the OP either answer the question or move on.

There is no law that forbids anyone from selecting and using the oldest available technology. It is also not our task to judge OP's and community members in asking or answering such questions. It is however our task to share our knowledge on reasonable alternatives/more suitable solutions (like we do, for example, in case of obvious [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issues).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Did my post really need that *improvement*?

Answer (score 27):

The thing to focus on is making sure they've applied the proper tag. If it's not immediately clear from the question which one applies, then your best course of action is to leave a helpful comment like this:

> I'm not sure if you meant ASP (classic) or ASP.NET - would you mind editing your question to make it clearer, and perhaps include [state what they forgot to include]

If it *is* clear which technology they're working with, and they simply applied the wrong tag, re-tag the question and leave a comment like this:

> The [foo] tag is actually for folks dealing with the newer [foo], since you're dealing with the older one, make sure to use [foo-classic] - it helps ensure folks still working with this see your question quickly.

Now, on to the touchier part of it - asking someone *why* they're using something old when something much newer and perhaps better exists. That gets tricky, here's the best way I've found to work through it:

#### Is it deprecated?

There's no reason to avoid letting someone know that the thing they're working with is very soon going to go away, and perhaps the reasons why. Take for instance [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) - they're *still* helping people to avoid using a plethora of deprecated (and potentially unsafe) `mysql_` functions.

You're better off pointing this out in an *answer*, though, showing the correct things to use and how to use them. Of course, some horses have been beaten to death in that regard - comments are fine too, just use your best judgement.

#### Is it dangerous?

Who needs toenail clippers when you've got a perfectly good toaster and a duck? Yeah, you know those questions. Enlighten them politely, to the extent that your patience permits you to do so.

#### Is it just ... old?

You see this in various ways, from someone using an ancient compiler to someone just finding something that they seem to have a knack for, and wanting to continue using it. I tend to enjoy these 'throwback' questions because they quite often lead me to digging up code I wrote *years* ago just to see how I solved something way back when.

Constraints can be *really* annoying, especially in enterprise applications. Take [mixel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746347/mixel), for example, who ['quitted' his job and found a better one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568471/pass-nothing-from-javascript-to-vbscript-in-ie9) after a very depressing adventure with vbscript. Realize that sometimes folks have no choice, and asking them why they're doing something in such an awfully painful way is like rubbing salt in it.

There's no problem, however, with *asking* what these crazy constraints might be - in fact misery loves company more than anything. You can approach it like this:

> I can help you do this using [newer thing], it's not particularly easy using [old thing], would that be helpful or do you need / prefer to stay with [old thing]?

You'll either get a yes, a no, or *man, my job really sucks, let me tell you what they're making me do*.

However, when it's pretty clear that the choice of technology is deliberate, do exercise some discretion. While you *are* trying to be helpful, it's easy to come off as being a bit pedantic. If possible, offer the advice in a form of an answer, indicating that it's *much* easier and saner to do it with the newer stuff.

And if anyone brow-beats me with Visual Studio while I'm trying to have some happy time with a virtual machine, FreeDOS and my long-cherished copy of Turbo C++, you'll see an ape get mad ;)

Comment: Tim, FYI, the OP now states that he has switched to .NET and used a database, and that it solved all of his problems. It seems that my instinct was correct, and that he was not _deliberately_ using Classic ASP.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yeah, I think you did the right thing there. It's a sense of discretion that just takes some time to sharpen. The 'stop spamming' thing is actually something that comes up on a semi-regular basis (I see it mostly from comment flags), so I tried my best to give a reasonably broad answer.

Comment: `Who needs toenail clippers when you've got a perfectly good toaster and a duck?` X like

Comment: @TimPost Don't have a problem with people pointing out to new users that they may have mis-tagged questions, just don't agree with John's approach a lot of the time. The way you suggested wording it was *(in my opinion)* far more respectful and doesn't jump to the conclusion they are committing some cardinal sin.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Plus the fact the OP managed to get the code to work suggests they have setup IIS and installed Classic ASP support, does that not sound *"deliberate"* to you?

Comment: @Lankymart the summer of love is long gone. _"Dude, you know classic ASP is ancient and you'd probably don't want to use it for new development"_ brings along exactly the same suggestion and holds exactly the same truth as the phrases supposed in this post. Don't get angry over the wording, appreciate the message.

Comment: @CodeCaster That wasn't what was said it was far more disrespectful  and I wasn't the only one that agreed. I don't appreciate been made to feel I'm doing something wrong because I develop in Classic ASP still. Oh no it's *"ancient"* and *"not supported"*, it works what support do I need? Just for the record I also write .Net (vb and c#) in it's various flavours. Like I said I have no problem with the OP being informed of alternatives just the manner in which it is done.

Comment: @Lankymart: It's not disrespectful of the newbie who has made a mistake to tell him he's made a mistake. And I just don't _care_ about disrespecting Classic ASP itself. It doesn't have feelings to hurt.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Of the Classic ASP community as a whole!! It's that attitude right there in [your comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275089/how-to-find-out-if-a-google-error-has-been-made/275126?noredirect=1#comment109272_275126) that really annoys me!

Comment: @Lankymart: I was not addressing myself to the Classic ASP community.

Comment: Interestingly, most of the Turbo C questions I see are not from nostalgic users, but from people taking classes in 3rd-world countries where that's the most up-to-date system they have!

Comment: That "quitted my job" post you linked to has been cracking my IT friends and I up all day - thanks for the laughs, Tim =)

Comment: @Gabe I know, we should all unite to give Iceland a more modern C library and compiler.